# Why does Neo see the Matrix code in different colors, Including gold?

Tags: analysis, the-matrix, film-analysis

In the *Matrix* movies, Neo's ability to see the Matrix code evolves, with some people appearing in gold and others in different colors.

Is there a symbolism behind these color variations in how Neo perceives the Matrix code?

Comment: Gold people (and things) appear to be programs.

Comment: @Valorum, when Neo first sees code in the original movie he sees everything and "everyone" as green code, including Agents, which are programs. First "golden" thing he sees is Seraph in the first sequel, who is, ofc, a program. But the rest of "golden" things are not even in the Matrix itself — they're real world machines (squids and the inhabitants of 01), and, ofc, agent Smith's copy that possessed a human body.

Comment: @user28434 - I didn't say that all programs show up in gold, just that the things he sees in gold appear to be programs or controlled by the machines.

Comment: "*Is there a symbolism behind these color variations?*" -> according to the ["*Color in Film series*"](https://cinegrading.com/blogs/all/color-in-film-case-study-the-matrix-1999) by Cinegrading, yes. Is that what you're looking for? Is it useful? Enough for an answer?

Comment: *others in different colors*? Seriph is gold; that's about it. Other colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Green** is the color of the Matrix, and represents the Mind.
>
> **Blue** is the “*Real World*” and represents the Body.
>
> **Yellow**<sup>1</sup> is the world of the Machines.
>
> **Brown, yellow, and orange** (gold) is the home of humanity in Zion.
>
> **Red** is the symbol for corruption, evil, and Hell; it represents risk, excitement, and danger.

These are excerpts and there are more in-depth explanations in [Color in film: case study - The Matrix (1999)](https://cinegrading.com/blogs/all/color-in-film-case-study-the-matrix-1999) and [Colour and meaning in The Matrix universe](https://rapidnotes.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/colour-and-meaning-in-the-matrix-universe/), from where these definitions were taken (and I keep it to the minimum here as I don't want to copy their work).

<sup>1. can be seen as gold too, depending on one's perception of colors.</sup>